# Cannot copy file to local storage android flutter

Tags: flutter, filesystems, imagepicker

I am trying to pick image from gallery or camera by image_picker, and save image at specific location. My code work perfectly when i pick image from camera, but it through  an exception when i pick from gallery while saving. Here is my code

```
onPressed: () async {
  final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  File tempFile = File(image.path);
  tempFile = await tempFile.copy('storage/emulated/0/$image.name');
}
```

Above code through an exception

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'storage/emulated/0//6544578463230218846.jpg', path = '/data/user/0/com.example.nysu/cache/image_picker6544578463230218846.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Flow of my application is that, firs i choose image from gallery or camera and then i input name for image from user and then i save image with user provided name to local storage.

So in between interval of choosing image and after that input name, cache memory for image picker is lost some time, because of this **(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)** happens.

To solve this i input name before choosing image, and instantly save image after choosing them. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you have the required permissions:
For example for Android you need:

Also the file path seems a bit weird with the extra "/", you might want to fix that if it is not intentional:
'storage/emulated/0//6544578463230218846.jpg'

Like so:

```
tempFile = await tempFile.copy('storage/emulated/0$image.name');
```